# What is the effect if a useEffect listens to a non-state value, of having a non-state value in the dependency array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Each time `Comp` re-renders, `rand` will be a different value. Will it trigger the `useEffect`?

```
function Comp({}) {
  const rand = Math.random();

  useEffect(() => {
    // do stuff
  }, [rand])
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any variable can go in the dependency array, `state` or not. And as long as it's in the array and it changes, `useEffect`'s callback gets re-executed.

Now, how `useEffect` notices that change? Well, it does a diff whenever the component renders.  And only a `state` change with a `setState` can trigger a render (not talking about renders because of parent component rendering here).

> If you already understood the mechanism, you could stop here, and go build your amazing product with React :). Otherwise, keep reading. I made up an example to explain more.

Say we have the below component. We should have `Hello Word` logged in the console when the component renders the first time, and every time `rand` changes. Clicking on that `button` changes `rand`, but we won't have a new log, because there isn't any re-render as no `state` has changed, so `useEffect` didn't do a diff, so it's not aware of the change.

```js
export default function Comp() {
  let rand = Math.random();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hello Word");
  }, [rand]);
  return (
      <button onClick={() => { rand = Math.random() }}>
        New value
      </button>
  );
}
```

Let's take this same component, and change it a little bit, as below. Now every time you click on the button the component re-renders, because we are setting a `state` with `setState`, and while re-rendering if the value of `rand` changes from the previous one, we will get a new log.

```js
export default function Comp() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true); // new line added
  let rand = Math.random();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hello Word");
  }, [rand]);
  // notice that the click handler has changed
  return (
      <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>
        New value
      </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time that the component will be re-render the `Math.random` method will be evaluated, so it will cause the `useEffect` to run again (with the exception that `rand` has changed).

Instead, if it will be just a constant, it will not re-run the `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

If you `console.log("hello")` inside the `useEffect`, you'll see that you only see two console's showing `"hello"` (because of `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount`). This means that your component will only re-render if a value of a state variable has changed or props that is been passed to this is changed (of course, the props passed have to be a state. Otherwise, it won't re-render).

Conclusion: Only a change in the value of **state** or **props** in a component re-renders the component.