# State inside useImperativeHandle is not stateful

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I have this state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

And put it inside `useImperativeHandle` like this:

```
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
   data,
}));
```

When I use `useEffect` to track if the state is changing like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(componentRef.current.data);
}, [componentRef.current.data])
```

It doesn't work, only when I manually check it, like having a button `onClick` which will print it out, otherwise it's not stateful. Why is it and is there any other way to make it work? Or is the only way to move the state out to parent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the effect if a useEffect listens to a non-state value, of having a non-state value in the dependency array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72508690/what-is-the-effect-if-a-useeffect-listens-to-a-non-state-value-of-having-a-non)

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is not reactive. It does not track things. It just compares the dependencies between renders and if there is a difference, it executes the given callback. The component that has the `useEffect` should **rerender** in order to execute that function.

What you can do is to pass callback from parent to child so the child can call it when it changes the state